# Selenium WebDriver Write data line by line into CSV

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I am trying to Write some data in a CSV file using Selenium

While running the Code

```
labels = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class="question-hyperlink"]')
text = [x.text for x in labels]
data.append(text)
print(text)
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as data_file:
    writer = csv.writer(data_file)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

the output am getting is

```
data1  data2  data3  data4  data5
data6  data7  data8  data9  data10
data11 data12 data13 data14 data15
```

But I want to write the data as below

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
.....
data15
```

How can I do that?
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter='\n')` delimiter

```
labels = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class="question-hyperlink"]')
text = [x.text for x in labels]
data.append(text)
print(text)
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as data_file:
    writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter='\n')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `data.append(text)` to `data.extend(text)`.
In such a way you will have a flat list `data` instead of list of lists.

In order to have a single value per row, you need to make
each item in `data` a singleton list

```
 writer.writerows(map(lambda x: [x], data))
```