# Why can't I scrape class elements using for loop in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this [website](https://www.gharghaderi.com/) using python programming language and selenium. I was able to scrape data easily without for loop but whenever I use for loop to scrape elements I get errors, I also tried using while loop with try and except but it was no help at all. This is my python code:

```
from logging import exception
from typing import Text
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
from selenium import webdriver 
PATH = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/scripts/chromedriver.exe" #always keeps chromedriver.exe inside scripts to save hours of debugging
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH) #preety i,portant part
driver.get("https://www.gharghaderi.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
house = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('griddetails')
for x in house:
    driver.get(x)
print(x.text)
```

and this is the error I am  constantly getting [error after using for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9sWG.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to find from  class `griddetails` , you want href??

Comment: I want prices of house, land, owner name. I am actually making house price prediction system for which  price , land area are necessary parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this  :

```
for x in house:
```

this means, for every x in house list.

your house list contains, all the Web elements with class `griddetails`

and in loop you are doing

```
driver.get(x)
```

which means you want to open every web element, which is wrong.

moreover `get()` supports URL in string format.

instead if you want to just print the details you can do this  :

```
house = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('griddetails')
for x in house:
   print(x.text)
```

this should give you proper output.

**sample output  :**

```
रु. 2,50,00,000
Land: 0-4-0-4 Road: 12 ft
Chapali 2 Budhanilkantha, Kathmandu
Chandra Bahadur Karki
ID 472
```

**Update 1 :**

```
house_list = []
house = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('griddetails')
for x in house:
   house_list.append(x.text)
data = {
         'Details': house_list
        }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv('out.csv', index = 0)
```

**Imports :**

```
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for, any ideas how to convert this in JSON or csv.

Comment: for writing to csv, can you follow this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571530/selenium-webdriver-write-data-line-by-line-into-csv

Comment: the link you provided was helpful to some extent but I was not able to convert scrapped data into csv, I read official python documentation of csv files and understood writer and reader methods but still could not convert it into csv

Comment: You want to write it to csv right ? I can assist you. we will use pandas for that

Comment: yes. I need csv file to import it into pandas and then use it for local house price prediction. in the link u provided I cant understand what data is used for.. I have basic knowledge of pandas

Comment: I have updated the code with pandas above, do check it out the updated 1 code

Comment: so here  data is a dictionary to create column. I want to learn more about adding separate columns and assigning related data , like location column mapped to name of location..is there any documentation for that , there are very little selenium scraping resources compared to beautifulsoup4... u can ignore this question if u like..

Comment: see here, we have a single list for everything. if I was doing this project, I would have created multiple lists object such as 1 list for price, 1 for name, and 1 for location, etc. and then would have parsed every list in the dictionary like I did above. generally I see here if I can find any solution, I really don't have any documentation that I can rely on.

Comment: yes, that makes more sense.. I shall try doing the same...

Comment: Sure, and you can always create a ticket here if something is not working, community would be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates an issue with the driver.get(x) line inside the for loop (line 19).
driver.get() expects an URL to open. However, I believe you pass it HTML bits with class name griddetails. What you want is the text inside that HTML.

Inside the loop try printing x or x.text and see what x is. Then you should try to find out how to extract the text you want.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZuhP.png)
Looks like the text you want is inside the span tag. So try looking there and find a way to extract the text from there. Sorry, I can't test the code myself atm.